# How does one access Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51

How does one get to Area 51? I'd like to see the list of proposals and see how the process works, but I cannot find the starting point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is [linked](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) in the footer:

[image: area51]

Comment: So simple! I knew I was being silly (and too tired...)

Comment: @Szymon - what are you doing up at this time? Go to sleep.

Answer (score 9):

Google [found it](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)! You can learn more about it and its process [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

[image]

Comment: google found it... lol...

Answer (score 2):

Try typing [area51.stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com) in a browser.

Comment: -1 I don't like typing

Comment: really! a -1 for that.. :(

Comment: @ColeJohnson But with the text you'd need to type provided you can copy and paste! (I would describe to you how to do that, but comments have too few characters to describe it in a manner that is understandable for people of all levels of computer knowledge)

Comment: Or just click the link.

Comment: @AlEverett I think you took the sarcasm out of the answer... (dunno if it's good or bad, lol!)

Comment: I really don't understand the downvotes seriously. Isn't the answer "not working" for *everyone*. I used to think, As long as it works for most of people on SO/SOmeta it is considered a solution. Is that not the case? What is so negative about typing, I dont understand?

Comment: @AlEverett there was no link at first.

Comment: @Sid I've removed it now that a link has been added :) However, wouldn't this be a link only answer? ;)

Comment: -1 not enough jquery

Comment: I don't find the need to catch the same ear other way round. The whole point is when things can be done the easy way, why complicate for the sake of amusement!

Comment: @Sid There's lots of downvoting going on on meta - for silly reasons too. My questions has as many upvotes as downvotes now. Why? Who knows...

Answer (score 2):

There is no [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Or is there? You can find what some may consider Area 51 in the new Stack Exchange explorer

[image]